# CSS border width sets height of border, not width

Tags: css

I am using `border-width: 100px;` in an attempt to set the horizontal width to `100px`, but it instead sets the height to `100px`.

Help appreciated.

```css
.border-top-green {
  border-top: 1px solid #4C9962;
  border-width: 100px;
  padding-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="border-top-green">Strong Leadership</h4>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such border "width" like you require. All borders are 100% of their respective side. You will need to fake a border using a pseudo element

```css
.border-top-green {
  padding-top: 16px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}

.border-top-green:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #4C9962;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="border-top-green">Strong Leadership</h4>
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't get it to display in the correct position on a [live site](https://divi.dev.insightdesign.com.au/agrimin/) (just above "SPECIALTY FERTILISER COMPANY" which is above "Better Nutrition comes from Better Fertiliser")

Comment: See my changes to the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<td style="text-align:center; border:2px solid #333;padding-bottom:2mm">
                <img src="<?= sprintf('QR-IDN.%03d-%s-%03d.png', $page, date('my'), ($row * 22 + $cell)) ?>" style="width:1.7cm;height:1.7cm;">
                <div style="font-size:5pt;"><?= sprintf('%03d-%s-%03d', $page, date('my'), ($row * 22 + $cell)) ?></div>
            </td>
```

" style="width:1.7cm; height:1.7cm;">

Any can solve to add width and height
width:1.7cm; height:2.0cm

Answer (score -1):

Is this you are looking for?

```css
.border-top-green {
  border-top: 1px solid #4C9962;
  border-width: 100px;
  padding-top: 16px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="border-top-green">Strong Leadership</h4>
```